# Azure Service Bus - random deserialization issues

Tags: azure, queue, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I've been recently having problems with my Service Bus queue. Random messages (one can pass and the other not) are placed on the deadletter queue with the error message saying:

```
"DeadLetterReason": "Moved because of Unable to get Message content There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The input source is not correctly formatted."
"DeadLetterErrorDescription": "Des"
```

This happens even before my consumer has the chance to receive the message from the queue.

The weird part is that when I requeue the message through Service Bus Explorer it passes and is successfully received and handled by my consumer.

I am using the same version of Service Bus either for sending and receiving the messages:

```
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, version: 7.2.1
```

My message is being sent like this:

```
        await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connString);
        var sender = client.CreateSender(endpointName);
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage(serializedMessage);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Comment: I've seen something like this in the past when working with old versions of the sdk / new versions of the sdk (consumer and producer) using different versions

Comment: PS: You don't need to use the same version, I'm just saying it happened with me in the past on that scenario

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Do you remember how you handled this issue back then?

Comment: upgraded the oldest SDK

Comment: Thiago's thought is a good one.  The key observation is that passing though Service Bus Explorer changes the outcome.  Depending on which version of Service Bus Explorer you're using, it may be internally using the (very) old `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` library - which has an opinionated implementation of serialization that requires [special handling]((https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample08_Interop.md)) to interop.  `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` and `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` are fully compatible with each other.

Comment: @JesseSquire is there a way to check the Azure Service Bus version in Portal Azure? I've been digging through but can't see detailed information. Both my receiver and sender use the same version of the same library (as stated in the original question).

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, but to add to it I am using Service Bus Explorer in version 5.0.2

Comment: There's no way to query the SDKs being used with Service Bus, through the portal or otherwise.   So long as the correct protocol and service contract are used, any caller can interact with the broker - be it an official SDK or other tool.

Comment: It looks like Service Bus Explorer is referencing both the current generation and the legacy SDK in v5.0.2  _([ref](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/blob/4c17cef718ab4806925f56f875794b8cd1e51c72/src/Common/Common.csproj))_.    I can't speak to what each is being used for, however.

Comment: Thanks for the input @JesseSquire, much appreciated. However, I think we start to deviate from the main question which is why random messages are placed on the deadletter queue. I must understand this first

Comment: Not so much a deviation as you may think.   We believe this error is surfaced by a `DataContractSerializer`, as it's not something that the SDK emits.   We've seen it [once before](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21932) but haven't been able to repro nor capture enough context to uncover the root.

Comment: I deployed a version with the updated package of Service Bus. I will post an updated later to tell whether 7.3.0 resolved the issue or not.

Comment: Well, it did not help. Still getting random messages in the deadletter queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I have for now for the described issue is that I implemented a retry policy for the messages that land on the dead-letter queue. The message is cloned from the DLQ and added again to the ServiceBus queue and for the second time there is no problems and the message completes successfully. I suppose that this happens because of some weird performance issues I might have in the Azure infrastructure. But this approach bought me some time to investigate further.